# Navigation links change on scroll position (single page site)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and javascript. I'm trying to create a single page website. The navigation is fixed at the top. When at a new 'part' of the single page I want the navigation to show that and the part currently on to be highlighted in the navigation.

I managed to somewhat do it with the scroll() but it only works if the variable 'top' is greater than 0. I know it is something probably really stupid I'm doing wrong but I'm new to this so I hope this doesn't bother you.

http://jsfiddle.net/mAPh6/

```
$(document).scroll( function() {
    var top = $(document).scrollTop();

    if ( 200 > top > 0 )
        $(".navLinkTop").css("border-bottom", "5px solid #fff568");
    else
        $(".navLinkTop").css("border-bottom", "none");

    if ( 400 > top > 200 )
        $(".navLinkAbout").css("border-bottom", "5px solid #fff568");
    else
        $(".navLinkAbout").css("border-bottom", "none");

    if ( 400 > top > 0 )
        $(".navLinkWork").css("border-bottom", "5px solid #fff568");
    else
        $(".navLinkWork").css("border-bottom", "none");

    if ( 400 > top > 0 )
        $(".navLinkContact").css("border-bottom", "5px solid #fff568");
    else
        $(".navLinkContact").css("border-bottom", "none");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do something like `a > b > c` it does not read out as "a is greater than b *and* b is greater than c". Rather, what happens is the following:

1. `a > b > c` evaluates to
2. `(true) > c` (assuming a is indeed greater than b) which evaluates to
3. `Number(true) >  c` since there is type conversion, which evaluates to
4. `1 > c` which is pretty random

So, `3 > 2 > 0` is true, but `3 > 2 > 1` is false. Generally, you just need to use `&&` when you're doing **AND**.

This is because the `>` operator is binary, that is it takes two arguments.

What you need to do is `(a > b) && (b > c)`, `&&` means "and"

In your case, this means changing statements like  `200 > top > 0` to `(top < 200) && (top > 0)`

Comment: Ahhh, I see, that works! Thank you so much! I'll accept as answer as soon as I can. Thanks.